# How do I pass a query string param to the Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-param

I am passing in a query string param to the VisualForce page. How can I pass it to the Controller, without having to click a button, so I can save the value as a field to a custom object.

Can I do an  apex:inputHidden to pass the value?

This is how I grab the query value

```
  keyword="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.d}"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can retrieve parameters passed in the URL directly:

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('d')
```

Comment: Beat me while I was looking it up! I'll remove my duplicate answer. :)